# Conversion problem from ArcMap to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I am trying to convert coordinates from ArcMap to QGIS, as the project that I am working on is in ArcMap, but I only have ArcMap on the University computer and I would like to work from home, furthermore, I do not have experience with ArcMap.

In ArcMsp, when I go to the Layer properties and then select the "Extend" tab I see the coordinates (top, left, right, bottom) in the **DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4** coordinate system.

In QGIS, I imported, via the XYT Tiles Plugin Google Satellite, a satellite image of the world. Now set the coordinate system to **DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4**, which I believe is the same as in ArcMap (not sure if "-Kruger" might be my problem, but I couldn't find "just" Gauss).

However, when I now export the layer in QGIS with the "Save As"- Function and applying the coordinates of ArcMap to QGIS (north, east, west, south) the wrong location is saved.

Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am using ArcMap 10.7.1

I need the images from the project as these are historical and I want to cut out this area in the present-day from Google Satellite. I already "extracted" them from the project and tried loading them into QGIS. Google Satellite automatically uses the **EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator** CRS and the historical image automatically uses the **EPSG:31468 - DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4** CRS. However, when I import the historical image I get the following prompt:

[image: Prompt]

I guess this is just the warning that QGIS will transform the image to the WGS 84 CRS.

Do I have to enter something for the Destination Transform?

Right now I just click okay, as WGS 84 is the same CRS as Google Satellite uses. But, this results in the historical image being way off.

Comment: Maybe you could use WGS 84 as exchange fromat? CRS 1 => WGS 84 => CRS 2

Comment: Do you know the projection of your initial layer? You probably mean this one [EPSG:31468](https://epsg.io/31468).

Comment: @Mr. Che, do you know why such conversation is required?

Comment: @Taras This is just my guess. Perhaps CRS with the same name in QGIS and ArcGIS may have different parameters.

Comment: Thank you @Mr. Che ... just wanted to say that sometimes it helped me as well to handle some transformations. But do not understand why

Comment: I don't get why you have to set anything? When saving a shapefile a `.prj` is saved, too, and this tells the GIS where to place the features. Just import the shapes into a blank project and they should be fine.

Comment: @Taras yes this one is the initial Projection

Comment: @Mr. Che I already kind of tried this (see my second edit)

Comment: @Erik I have this .prj file in the ArcGIS project, though I cannot import it to QGIS

Comment: The `.prj` is part of the `.shp`. You simply import the `.shp` and everything should be fine.

Comment: @Erik I don't have a .shp. I have the original ArcMap project (.mxd), the images (.ecw and .tif), for some images a .prj file and some files I do not know what they do (.tfwx and tif.ovr). But, I think that when I load the .mxd file all of the .prj files are also loaded automatically. And therefore I thought I could just use the information under Layer Properties to "find" the correct area in Google Satellite in QGIS, where I cannot load the .prj file.

Comment: Maybe next time tell us right away, that you only have images.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can use an exchange format, for example, the [WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)](https://epsg.io/4326) coordinate system. First, convert your data in ArcGIS to a WGS 84 projection, then use QGIS to convert back to the original projection.