# Aerial images coordinate conversion problem from ArcMap to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcmap

I have multiple different historical aerial images from an ArcMap project and I want to "extract" somehow the present-day satellite image of their areas from Google Satellite.

So what I tried to do is, import Google Satellite with the XYZ Tiles Plugin, set the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) to DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4 ([EPSG:31468](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-gauss-kruger-zone-4/)), which is the CRS from the images, and saved the area with the Layer --> Save As functionality, using the coordinates of the images as north, east, south, west.

However, this does not work. I either get a blank (white) image or the image is of a completely different location and if I just import the image into QGIS it is also not at the right location.

Yet, when I import the image into ArcMap it is at the correct position.

The output of gdalinfo on one of the images is:

```
gdalinfo 1978-03.tif

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 1978-03.tif
       1978-03.tif.ovr
       1978-03.tif.aux.xml
Size is 10766, 10619
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (0.000000000000000,147.486111111111114)
Pixel Size = (0.013888888888889,-0.013888888888889)
GCP Projection = 
PROJCS["DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_4",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
        DATUM["Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
            SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",4500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",12.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","31468"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=, Info=
          (8924.44718310842,9456.67887323909) -> (4469283.68817037,5535422.30978963,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=, Info=
          (9056.91760563757,9337.02816901542) -> (4469314.11531456,5535445.32858567,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=, Info=
          (7505.95437375864,7683.60903820582) -> (4469025.98348829,5535792.51553005,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=, Info=
          (7620.95041533496,7634.67871375615) -> (4469048.63186693,5535802.46388328,0)
GCP[  4]: Id=, Info=
          (10292.3337961421,8017.17334593507) -> (4469579.09605285,5535697.31825632,0)
GCP[  5]: Id=, Info=
          (10244.4309673187,8520.11818380561) -> (4469562.48018629,5535595.82388666,0)
GCP[  6]: Id=, Info=
          (6920.10031108643,7016.7363824416) -> (4468912.66221999,5535935.89352514,0)
GCP[  7]: Id=, Info=
          (1976.54547536775,749.573714908212) -> (4467982.38535943,5537290.12192803,0)
GCP[  8]: Id=, Info=
          (6453.23938492237,865.984278769698) -> (4468902.69622784,5537184.68525883,0)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2015:05:11 07:26:38
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CS4 Windows
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (       0.000,     147.486) 
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Upper Right (     149.528,     147.486) 
Lower Right ( 149.5277778,   0.0000000) 
Center      (  74.7638889,  73.7430556) 
Band 1 Block=10766x24 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 5383x5310, 2692x2655, 1346x1328, 673x664, 337x332, 169x166
```

As I have zero experience with ArcMap, I thought about using QGIS for this task. Furthermore, I can only use ArcMap at my University.

Comment: Is this related to your previous question?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/356815/115  If so, that's important background information to provide to potential answerers so that they can work out whether this is a new question or a duplicate.  Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Yes, it somewhat is, however, I realized that I don't need to import the historical images to QGIS, instead I just need the (correct) coordinates to export the present-day images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by importing the images to ArcMap and then exporting them without generating the auxiliary files.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it is better to export the visual content of your map canvas in QGIS: Project->Import/Export->Save Map as Image. Don't forget to check the "Append georeference information" Checkbox: https://youtu.be/xY-JR-mr57Y

[image]